# JavaScript: Change values in an object in a while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of JavaScript objects which have a property 'table', this property can have a value of table1, table2, table3, or table4. The value of the property is randomly generated. Each table should only have 6 members. I have a while loop which checks if say 'table1' has more than 6 values. What I'm having trouble with is changing each 'table1' value until less than 6 objects have a value of 'table1'.

Array of Objects:

```
  var data = [{
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
        {
            name: "",
            pref: "",
            table: ""
        },
    ];
```

While Loop:

```
function countTable(value) {
        return function (sum, item) {
            return sum + (item.table === value);
        };
    }

    function check() {
      while (data.reduce(countTable('table1'), 0) >= 6) {
          // I need help here
      }
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not solving the issue at the time you assign the table values randomly? With a little protection you can avoid assigning the same name more than 6 times:

```
let counts = [[1, 6], [2, 6], [3, 6], [4, 6]];
data.forEach( obj => {
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * counts.length);
    obj.table = 'table' + counts[i][0];
    if(--counts[i][1] == 0) counts.splice(i, 1);
});
```

```js
const data = [{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: ""
}];

let counts = [[1, 6], [2, 6], [3, 6], [4, 6]];
data.forEach( obj => {
    let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * counts.length);
    obj.table = 'table' + counts[i][0];
    if(--counts[i][1] == 0) counts.splice(i, 1);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

When you already had randomly assigned table values, and need to re-assign in cases where there are more than 6 of the same, then it could look like this:

```
let counts = [6, 6, 6, 6];
let tables = [1, 2, 3, 4];
data.forEach( obj => {
    let i = obj.table.slice(-1) - 1;
    if (counts[i]) { // It's OK
        counts[i]--;
        return; 
    }
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * tables.length);
    i = tables[j];
    obj.table = 'table' + i;
    counts[i]--;
    if (!counts[i]) tables.splice(j, 1);
});
```

The snippet starts with data having too many `table3` values:

```js
var data = [{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table1"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table2"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table4"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table1"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table2"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table4"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table4"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table1"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table2"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table4"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table2"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table4"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table1"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table2"
},{
    name: "",
    pref: "",
    table: "table3"
}];

let counts = [6, 6, 6, 6];
let tables = [1, 2, 3, 4];
data.forEach( obj => {
    let i = obj.table.slice(-1) - 1;
    if (counts[i]) { // It's OK
        counts[i]--;
        return; 
    }
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * tables.length);
    i = tables[j];
    obj.table = 'table' + i;
    counts[i]--;
    if (!counts[i]) tables.splice(j, 1);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem. I have one more issue with it, but it's not pertaining to your method just something else in my code that I have yet to find.

Comment: You're welcome, don't hesitate to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using the forEach method of an array.

```
var counts = {};
data.forEach(elt => counts[elt.table] ? counts[elt.table]++ : counts[elt.table] = 1);
```

This will give you a table of table counts.

You could use the filter method with this technique to eliminate excess objects:

```
const max = 6;
var counts = {};
data = data.filter(elt => {
    counts[elt.table] ? counts[elt.table]++ : counts[elt.table] = 1;
    return counts[elt.table] <= max;
);
```

Now you have a table showing what was there, and the excess elements are filtered away.

Comment: Ok, will this affect the original array of objects' values?

Comment: It doesn't touch the original array. Note that the elements of the filtered array are the elements of the original array (objects are passed around by reference).

If you want to change the original array, it's actually a fair bit more complex.

Comment: Oh, well I would need it to change the original array. Thanks for your help, though. I think the below answer may have solved it.